# How to show online offline status on Unix via putty

Tags: unix, status, putty

How can i show online offline status of a network ( such as "ftp" ) on Unix via putty ?

for example in solaris , we can type " svcs -a " command and then use "grep" to see the online & offline status of specific services. How can i see these statuses one by one on Unix ?

Comment: I really don't get it. What does one protocol (FTP) have to do with a client implementing a different protocol (SSH)? And what does it mean for "ftp" to have "online offline status"?

Comment: sorry , ftp was wrong . i'm  new in this business . i meant  for example in solaris , we can type " svcs -a " command and then use "grep" to see the status of specific services. How can i see these statuses one by one  on  Unix ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use netstat to see if some port (used by the service) is open or not.

```
ubuntu@ip:~/$ netstat -na --inet | grep LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
ubuntu@ip:~/$
```

Or for FTP:

```
netstat -na --inet | grep 21
```

I'm not sure what exactly does this command "svcs -a" (I did not use Solaris). But perhaps this command could help

```
service --status-all
```

Works on RedHat-like systems (SystemV init style). It shows all services' current status

```
[root@dgdevlin bin]# service --status-all
acpid (pid 3409) is running...
adlagent (pid  3738) is running...
anacron is stopped
atd (pid  3657) is running...
```

Also, if your linux is Ubuntu(-based) you can use this command

```
initctl list
```

It shows a list of services. For each service it shows configured state - whether the service should running after system is started, and current status of the service - is it running right now.

```
ubuntu@ip:~/$ initctl list
mountall-net stop/waiting
passwd stop/waiting
rc stop/waiting
rsyslog start/running, process 625
screen-cleanup stop/waiting
tty4 start/running, process 694
udev start/running, process 267
```

Comment: thanks that really helped but netstat is checking the ports its another way but  how can i see if its configurated  " online or offline " from the operating system ?

Comment: added some details to the answer.